# Possible to prevent ASP.NET from storing Request variables in memory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, securestring, request.form

Apparently, [using SecureString with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463821/is-there-any-benefit-to-using-securestring-in-asp-net) doesn't really make sense because ASP.NET automatically stores request parameters in plain text.  But is there a way to hack ASP.NET to make SecureString usable in this scenario?

For example, would it be possible to do something to hook into the ASP.NET pipeline **before** it has a chance to stash all of the request parameters in memory?  Something like a module, but I'm guessing that is too late.

Comment: And where to store it if not on memory ? I mean that you must have them somewhere....

Comment: Well maybe the code that parses the raw Request data into the Request.Params collections could be overridden to use SecureString instead for certain keys?

Comment: The  `Request.Params` reads all the QueryString, Form, Cookies and ServerVariables, all that are already public, especial the url parameters (query string).